# RSpec can't find nested formatter

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I am trying to run `rspec` only for Ruby (not Rails), for a simple Ruby file. I'm following Tut+ TDD Testing with Ruby.

I have a `competition` directory with a `lib` folder and `spec` folder.

```
├── lib  
│   ├── competition.rb  
│   └── team.rb  
└── spec  
    └── competition_spec.rb
```

When I run `rspec`, I got this error.  I could've sworn the rspec work before.  I don't know what happened.

```
competition :> rspec spec
/Users/akh88/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/rspec-core-> 3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:167:in `find_formatter': Formatter 'nested' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)
```

#### My `competition_spec.rb`

```
require_relative "../lib/competiiton.rb"  
require_relative "../lib/team.rb"  

describe Competition do
  let(:competition) {Competition.new}
  let(:team) {Team.new}

  context "having no questions" do
    before { competition.questions = [] }

    it "doesn't accept any teams" do
      expect do
        team.enter_competition(competition)
      end.to raise_error Competition::Closed
    end
  end
end
```

My `rvm` default Ruby version is 1.9.1 on Mac OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: Have you an `.rspec` file in main folder? it maybe contains wrong formatter.

Comment: `competition_spec.rb` is under `/spec` dir..right ?

Comment: yes competition_spec is in /spec

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `nested` formatter was used in RSpec 1. This was renamed `documentation` in RSpec 2.

Maybe you have specified `nested` on the command line  or in a `.rspec` file? Then you need to specify `--format documentation` instead.

Have you set `config.formatter = nested` somewhere, probably your `spec_helper.rb` file? Remove it.

You could have updated the RSpec gem from v1 (the command to run tests changed from `spec` to `rspec` though so that's hard to miss). You can check versions with `gem list rspec`.

Alternatively, you could be missing the load of a [custom formatter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters) you happened to call `nested`.

Comment: thank you, that is exactly the issue. I cd into my root directory, open the .rspec file, and change the "--format nested --color" to "--format documentation --color" and that seems to do the trick.  my rspec command now works.

Answer (score 10):

My .rspec file only had

```
--color
```

and I was still getting this error.

I explicitly set it to

```
--format documentation --color
```

And now it works.